# security threat warning when I use SmsManager

Tags: android, smsmanager

I have to create an android App that can send message automatically. I found the code that do what I want but this send me the following warning [it is a translation since my message it is not in english]:

```
security threat
AppName seems to be infected. We advise you to uninstall the app immediately.
```

The line that give me the warning is:

```
smsManager.sendTextMessage(phoneNo, null, message, null, null);
```

My code is:

```
public void sendSMSMessage() {
    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
            Manifest.permission.SEND_SMS)
            != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this,
                Manifest.permission.SEND_SMS)) {
        } else {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                    new String[]{Manifest.permission.SEND_SMS},
                    MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_SEND_SMS);
        }
    }
}

@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode,String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
    switch (requestCode) {
        case MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_SEND_SMS: {
            if (grantResults.length > 0
                    && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
                smsManager.sendTextMessage(phoneNo, null, message, null, null);
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "SMS sent.",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "SMS faild, please try again.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                return;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I want to point out that this code work. The only problem is that warning that I would like to eliminate.

I tried to send sms with intent but those method need human interaction and I do not want it (if possible).

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google has changed its security policies for dangerous permissions. As per it, you cant allow your app to handle such events without human interactions as these are dangerous permissions.

> Google Play restricts the use of high risk or sensitive permissions,
>   including the SMS or Call Log permission groups.

Check this link for further information on the same:

https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/9047303?hl=en